# Bin script works fine on Windows but fails bizarrely on Linux

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to write a small CLI helper for Node which lets me set environment variables across platforms. For example, if you have an NPM script like the following:

```
"something": "MY_VAR=thing node index.js"
```

`MY_VAR` will be unset on Windows. My solution was to write a tiny library which provides a new command that will run a subcommand with a given set of environment variables (example in [readme](https://github.com/eightyeight/envade#envade)). I tested and developed it in Windows, assuming that would be the more difficult environment to target, and got it working perfectly. However, when I then tried to test this on Linux, I get a strange error. I made a new project with this `package.json`:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "grunt": "grunt --help",
    "envade": "envade"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "envade": "^1.0.1",
    "grunt-cli": "^0.1.13"
  }
}
```

And then:

```
$ npm run envade

> @ envade /code
> envade

: No such file or directory

npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-57-generic
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "envade"
npm ERR! node v0.12.6
npm ERR! npm  v2.11.3
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! @ envade: `envade`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the @ envade script 'envade'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the  package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     envade
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls 
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /code/npm-debug.log
```

What could be going wrong here? `npm run grunt` works absolutely fine, and as far as I can tell I've followed the same application structure. I have attempted to rename `index.js` in `envade` to `index` (no file extension), but the same error appears to occur. I also tried replacing the contents of `index.js` with `console.log('hi');` after it was installed, to rule out errors in the script itself.

I originally followed [this guide](http://javascriptplayground.com/blog/2015/03/node-command-line-tool/) to creating Node scripts. I'm finding it really hard to google for this error since there's no filename!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is dos/windows newline (crlf). So, 'node^M' is interpreted as a file name in this line at your envade binary:

`#!/usr/bin/env node^M`

and of course the file can not be found...

P.S. You can fix the problem with the following command:

`sed -i 's/\r//' envade`

Comment: Oh wow. That's bizarre. And the carriage return is causing the `: No such ...` to overwrite the `node` at the start of the line. I could have sworn I told `git` to check in Unix endlines! Thanks for the quick answer.

Comment: Yes, of course, the installation `core.autocrlf` to `true` - a simpler solution.